# discord.js keeps receiving TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```js
for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
}
```

I keep on getting an error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

and it has been working flawlessly until now. I tried to `console.log(command.data)` but I can't seem to find what's wrong...

Comment: How does your command file look like? Please edit in an example

Comment: `command.data` is the common structure for Slash Commands, are you reading the type of command correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is telling that the `command.data.name` line doesn't exists in the file. So this error does not show up because of your `index.js` file but because one of the files that you are trying to read commands folder. You'll need to make sure that you have added in every file that is being read in the `index.js` (so in your case all the files in your commands file) in the module.exports the following json line:

```
module.exports = {
     data: {
         name: 'command_name'
     },
     ....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing `command.data.name` by `command.name`.

Your code should work if you have this :

```
for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}
```